# How to display a dialog every minute using WorkManager?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-workmanager

I got an app that's supposed to fetch user's location every 1 minute. If the location service is off, it'll show a dialog to the user in any fragment or activity. To do this, what's the best approach?

"I've implemented this approach using Service and EventBus. I'm looking for more efficient ways."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I wanna show a dialog in any fragment when the user turns off their internet or location.